# How to submit a form on page load without clicking submit button?

Tags: php

Is there a way to make a form submit "onload" without clicking a
submit button with PHP? i saw some ways to make it with Javascript, but i love php and id like to make it with php.

For example:

```
<form action="https://xxxxxx.com/yyy.php" method="post" id="foo">
<input type="hidden" name="LoginEmail" value="user [at] domain.com">
<input type="hidden" name="LoginPassword" value="mycleartextpassword">
<input type="submit" name="Authenticate" value="Login">
<input type="hidden" name="Action" value="1" >
</form>
```

I can make it with javascript:

```
<form id="foo"> .... < /form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc () {
        var frm = document.getElementById("foo");
        frm.submit();
    }
    window.onload = myfunc;
</script>
```

Well, Can we make same thing with PHP? Could you please kindly share your ideas and advices?

Thank you.

Comment: So, whats your mean? php can do that job? or cant make it? whats your mean

Comment: Ok, PHP is run in the server, so no, you can't.
However if your intent is to submit information to another script why not just redirect form your php to this other script, or submit via post with the help of CURL?

Comment: If you just want to send some params with the POST method, you don't to submit a form in php.
You can use curl (example: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl), stream context (example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), or directly with sockets (example: http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/post-request.htm)

Comment: thanks for advice. thats why ive written my question here. you have given perfect advice to me. im going to test your way. i think it will work. thanks for advice.

Comment: it can, but not how you are putting it. It can do the job on the server ( posting to another script), but not actually do something with the HTML like you have put there on the example.

Comment: this is not really what the OP wanted, although is a way to simulate the same process

Answer (score 4):

It isn't possible to carry out a client-side (i.e.: browser based) form submit action using a server side language (i.e.: PHP). It's a bit like trying to get a library to read a book, if that makes sense. (You get the books from the library and return them there, but the library itself can't read books.)

As such, JavaScript is your only solution if you require an automated submission. Even then, you need to ensure there's a "normal" solution for use by people who don't have JavaScript enabled. (The joy of graceful degradation, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

i had diffculty in dong this as well so thought i would post my solution here it goes...

this curl command posts the file to a url and send back any data it receives. It's posting an xml file which is why the content type is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded.The api i was posting to requested that the data be encoded which is why I use --data-urlencode. I also assign the filename with a post variable name here so its like posting an input field with a name="whatever".

```
curl --data-urlencode [post variable name]=@[filename] --header "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" http://[url to send file to]
```

Assigning the command to a variable is easy...see below
'

```
content=$(put curl command in here);
```

P.s DO NOT FORGET TO ESCAPE ANY '=' or '&' in your url's, this causes issues if you're trying to retrieve data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to auto-submit form after page load (IMHO it's pointless) I assume you generated its values by yourself (by PHP code) and you want to send them to another page, right? If so redirect page to the another by header() passing values through POST:

```
$post_data = 'LoginEmail=username [at] domain.com&LoginPassword=...';
$content_length = strlen($post_data);

header('POST /another_page.php HTTP/1.1');
header('Host: fancyhost');
header('Connection: close');
header('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
header('Content-length: ' . $content_length);
header('');
header($post_data);

exit();
```

Comment: thanks for advice. well, we found so many ways within the 5 minutes :) thats why i love php. there is always 1 more way in Php. thanks mate. im gonna test your way too.

Answer (score 0):

it is by using jquery ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function(){..........your code goes here........});
```

if you prefer jquery replay me i wll give you the help

Comment: actually i decided to make this job by Jquery + Php and i was creating it by Jquery's Post function :) then i saw your message while making it on my localhost :) i think jquery is best option. im gonna support jquery by php's while function. jquery also can give success information..

Answer (score 0):

Use printf to print your javascript code then when the client browser receives the page it will execute your javascript.

```
printf("<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc () {
        var frm = document.getElementById("foo");
        frm.submit();
    }
    window.onload = myfunc;
</script>");
```

I do this a lot for the mapping services.